# Power BI / Power Query [M code] - Add a custom column based on source

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, navision, m

```
let
Source = Sql.Databases("xx.x.x.x"),
zzz_LIVE = Source{[Name="NAVzzz_LIVE"]}[Data],
#"COMPANY1$G_L Entry" = NAVzzzLIVE{[Schema="dbo",Item="COMPANY1$G_L Entry"]}[Data],
```

Pulling data from several entities (companies) in Microsoft Dynamics Navision with above code (Company1 as an example).

Trying to add a custom column with an unique identifier based on the name of the company.

```
G_L Account number     G_L Account name   Amount   Company
10010                  Revenue            100      Company1
22000                  Rent               50       Company1
```

Is it possible to achieve this by M code?

Many thanks.

Comment: So you have multiple tables in your database that you want to load and append together with a column that tags the source?

Comment: Hi @AlexisOlson 

Correct, key is the unique identifier which would be dynamic depending on the source. 

Is it possible to extract a string from the source? The pattern would be the same, after Item= and before $G_L Entry

thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
let
    Source = Sql.Databases("xx.x.x.x"),
    zzz_LIVE = Source{[Name="NAVzzz_LIVE"]}[Data],
    Name1 = "Company1",
    Name2 = "Company2",
    [...]
    #"COMPANY1" = NAVzzzLIVE{[Schema="dbo",Item=Name1&"$G_L Entry"]}[Data],
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"COMPANY1", "Company", each Name1),
    #"COMPANY2" = NAVzzzLIVE{[Schema="dbo",Item=Name2&"$G_L Entry"]}[Data],
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"COMPANY2", "Company", each Name2),
    [...]
    Table.Combine(#"Added Custom1",#"Added Custom2",[...])
```

That way you

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this, but I think it might work for you:

```
let 
    Source = Sql.Databases("xx.x.x.x"), 
    zzz_LIVE = Source{[Name="NAVzzz_LIVE"]}[Data],
    #"COMPANY1$G_L EntrySrc" = NAVzzzLIVE{[Schema="dbo",Item="COMPANY1$G_L Entry"]},
    #"COMPANY1$G_L Entry" = #"COMPANY1$G_L EntrySrc"[Data],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"COMPANY1$G_L Entry", "Company",   
    each Record.Field(#"COMPANY1$G_L EntrySrc", "Item")) 
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

I split the Navigation step (#"COMPANY1$G_L Entry") in two so that I could reference its record. Otherwise, the [Data] gets in the way.

If I'm correct, it will return COMPANY1$G_L Entry into your new column. You could change `Record.Field(#"COMPANY1$G_L EntrySrc", "Item")` to `Text.Before(Record.Field(#"COMPANY1$G_L EntrySrc", "Item"), "$G_L")` to only return COMPANY1.